# How to define typedef of function pointer which has template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, typedef

I would like to make typedef for function pointer which has stl container as argument and this container has unknown type. Something like this:

```
typedef void (* TouchCallBack)(GLRenderer*, const MotionEvent&, std::vector<T >);
```

it's possible?  (especially in c++ 03)

Comment: Not in C++03, no, unless Boost or something has a trick up its sleeve.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've written but you have to be in a context (function or class template) where `T` is declared.

Comment: I mean the global static function

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I don't know of any C++03 solution exactly like that, and it's not built into the language, but in C++11, this is possible with `using` aliases:

```
template<typename T>
using TouchCallBack = void (*)(GLRenderer*, const MotionEvent&, std::vector<T >);
```

One workaround for C++03 is using a struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct TouchCallBack {
    typedef void (*type)(GLRenderer*, const MotionEvent&, std::vector<T >);
};

//use like TouchCallBack<int>::type
```