# Using typedefs to autofill a template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class: `template<typename Trait, Value> class Storage`. In one application where I use this class, I want to create a synonym for `Storage` that "auto-fills" in the `Value` to be `ValueA`. However, as the class is used elsewhere, it doesn't make sense to have Value be set to `ValueA` in Storage's definition.

I've attempted to create a typedef within the header for Storage, but I keep running into compiler errors. Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
template<typename trait>
typedef Storage<trait, ValueA> MyStorage<trait>;
```

So that I can use different traits, but have the value being stored automatically set. The error I get when I try this approach is **error: template declaration of 'typedef'**

Is there anyway around this limitation in C++03?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848924/how-to-define-typedef-of-function-pointer-which-has-template-arguments) help?

Comment: @chris: That's C++11

Comment: `template<typename trait> struct DefStorage : Storage<trait,ValueA> {};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest workaround is to simply use a new class

```
 template<typename trait> 
 struct DefStorage : Storage<trait,ValueA> 
 {};
```

*Technically* you have to be careful because this is easily convertible to a `Storage<trait,ValueA>*`, and if you `delete` that, the destructor for `DefStorage` doesn't get called, which is *technically* undefined behavior.  So be careful of that.  But as long as you aren't heap allocating these, there's nothing to be concerned about.