# How to typedef a function pointer with template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Consider this:

```
typedef void (*ExecFunc)( int val );

class Executor
{

  void doStuff() { mFunc( mVal ); }
  void setFunc( ExecFunc func ) { mFunc = func; }

  int           mVal;
  ExecFunc      mFunc;
};

void addOne( int val ) { val = val+1; } // this could be passed as an ExecFunc.
```

Very simple. Suppose now that I want to templatize this?

```
typedef void (*ExecFunc)( int val );    // what do I do with this?

template < typename X > class Executor
{

  void doStuff() { mFunc( mVal ); }
  void setFunc( ExecFunc<X> func ) { mFunc = func; }

  X                mVal;
  ExecFunc<X>      mFunc; // err... trouble..
};

template < typename X > addOne( X val ) { val += 1; }
```

So how to I create a templatized function pointer?

Comment: define it within the class using the template parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define typedef of function pointer which has template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848924/how-to-define-typedef-of-function-pointer-which-has-template-arguments)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C++11, you can use this:

```
template<class X>
using ExecFunc = void(*)(X);
```

defines `ExecFunc<X>`.

In C++03, you have to use this instead:

```
template<class X>
struct ExecFunc {
  typedef void(*type)(X);
};
```

and use `typename ExecFunc<X>::type` within `Executor`.