# Templates: Get type and map to function

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, types, function-pointers

I currently have a series of C++ functions that each call to a C function located elsewhere, these functions essentially do the same thing but return different types. I would like to be able to dynamically get the type of a template and call the associated function, something like

```
template<typename T>
T getVal(const char* id) {
    return funcMap[T.someIdentifyingMethod](id);
}
```

Is this possible and if so how would I go about it?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but maybe you want [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index)? Why do you need to do this dynamically?

Comment: Dynamically was perhaps the wrong word to use, basically I just want a convenient way of associating a type with a function, getting the type of a template as it is compiled and then using that association to insert the associated function into the template

Comment: Which are the intended types for *T*? I mean, it happens to be a primitive type like `int` or you use it with custom types? In the second case, there is one more solution I can put in a response.

Comment: The types will (fortunately) just be primitives

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you just want template specialisation:

```
template<typename T>
struct wrapper;

template<>
struct wrapper<int>
{
    static int getVal(char const* id) { /* ... */ }
};

template<>
struct wrapper<widget>
{
    static widget getVal(char const* id) { /* ... */ }
};
```

Then you would call `wrapper<T>::getVal(id)`.

Answer (score 1):

Template specialization indeed sems like what you're looking for. Here's how to specialize your free function, instead of a static member function that Simple proposed:

```
template<typename T>
T getVal(const char* id); // leave undefined to fail compilation when no specialization exists

template<>
int getVal(const char* id) {
    return c_function_that_returns_int(id);
}

template<>
foo getVal(const char* id) {
    return c_function_that_returns_foo(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go this way:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename ReturnType>
class fget
{
    typedef std::function<ReturnType(const char*)> func_type;
    func_type _f;
public:
    fget() = delete;
    fget(const func_type& f) : _f(f) {};
    ReturnType operator()(const char* id) { return _f(id); }
};

double minusPi(const char* id) { (void) id; return -3.14; }
unsigned long long getull(const char* id) { (void) id; return 123456789123456; }


#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    fget<double> mPi{minusPi};
    fget<unsigned long long> ull{getull};

    std::cout << mPi("hello") << std::endl;
    std::cout << ull("hello") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile & run with:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
```

[Live exemple on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eae73b31b8d9bb58). Output:

```
-3.14
123456789123456
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this trick. It associate a type with an object:

```
using type_id_t = void(*)();
template<typename T> void type_id(){}
```

Now, we can match an object (in your case, a function) with the function pointer of this template:

```
std::map<type_id_t, void(*)(const char*)> funcs;
```

And fill the map:

```
funcs[type_id<int>] = myFunc1;
funcs[type_id<double>] = myFunc2;
funcs[type_id<SomeOtherType>] = myFunc3;
```

Now you can retrieve them like this:

```
template<typename T>
T getVal(const char* id) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T(*)(const char*)>(funcMap[type_id<T>])(id);
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, however my compiler doesn't support template aliasing. I tried to use the trick described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848924/how-to-define-typedef-of-function-pointer-which-has-template-arguments, and then having the map as <type_id_t::type, void(*)(const char*), however I then had trouble inserting into the map ([] assignment came back with 'array bound is not a constant int'). Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake here, there is no template aliasing needed. See my edit. And the type of the map values should be `void(*)(const char*)`. Notice the two stars. Tell me if the error persist.

Comment: My compiler doesn't support 'using' for aliasing in general it seems, but after changing it to 'typedef void(*type_id_t)();', I am back to the old 'array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token' error in the map assignments

Comment: I don't know this error. However, what might work is to add the optional `&` with function pointer. So try this: `funcs[&type_id<int>] = ...`